How to efficiently send Firebase push notifications to 200,000 users simultaneously using PHP?
With a user base of 200,000 and a live session underway, the need to send push notifications to all users simultaneously arises to inform them of the live session in PHP. However, Firebase push notifications can only be sent to 1000 users at a time. This results in the last user receiving the notification 10 minutes after the session has gone live.
In light of this issue, what steps can be taken to address this limitation and ensure all users receive the notification promptly?
I have used below code
function sendMsg($regIds, $data, $device_type=''){
    $apiKey = "";
    $fields = array(
        'priority' => 'high',
        'data' => array(
            'title' => $this->data['title'],
            "body" => $this->data['message'],
            'sound' => 'default',
            'message' => $this->data['message'],
            'screen' => $this->data['screen'],
            'screen_id' => $this->data['screen_id']
        )
    );
    if($this->data['screen_data']) {
        $fields['data']['screen_data'] = $this->data['screen_data'];
    }
    if($this->data['notification_id']) {
        $fields['data']['notification_id'] = $this->data['notification_id'];
    }

    if(gettype($regIds) != 'array') {
        $fields['to'] = $regIds;
    }
    if($device_type != 'android') {
        $fields['notification'] = array(
            'title' => $this->data['title'],
            'body' => $this->data['message'],
            'sound' => 'default'
        );
    }
    if($fields) {
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: key='.$this->data['api_key'], 'Content-Type: application/json'));
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         return $result;
    }
}


If this is a built-in limitation of firebase, then the solution is likely to be "don't use firebase". Unless you can upgrade to a premium service or something - I'm not familiar with the platform, but would assume that's researchable already. In what way is this issue related to the "php" and "codeigniter" tags you've added, exactly? See also [ask]. Unless you have a problem specifically related to codeigniter code you've written, we don't need that tag

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927065/limit-of-bulk-firebase-cloud-messaging

@ADyson - I have included the PHP and CodeIgniter tags as I am seeking an example in this language. It appears that there may be some uncertainty in your response. I have thoroughly researched their services and it seems they do not offer a premium plan. However, given the vast world and community of Stack Overflow, there may be a solution available from someone in a remote corner. This is why I have reached out here for assistance.
If you read properly my question then you can see I have mentioned "PHP". :)
Thank you.

@tangentially-perpendicular - I don't understand why you are edited my question is there any issue with that line?

tangentially will have removed that line because your personal history has no relevance to the question (or any other question on this site). Stick to the actual issue. See also [ask]

Anyway yes of course I saw that you had mentioned PHP, but it's still unclear how it's relevant. If Firebase prevents you from sending more than 1000 messages at once, it won't matter if you use PHP, Java, Go, or raw binary 1s and 0s to send the request to Firebase - it still won't send more than 1000 messages simltaneously. You seem to be asking for some sort of magic workaround.

@ADyson - Thank you for the confirming. It is excellent to see that there is no way to send more than 1000 push notifications at a time. If you have any magic workaround then please share it with us :)

The point about magic is that it doesn't exist

On the thread I linked you to, someone suggests that Topic messaging doesn't have the same limitations. Not sure if you've read that or looked into it yet?

@PankajDhameliya ADyson has it right: I edited your question because your history is not relevant, but more than that. Starting a question with a phrase that amounts to "I'm really really good at this" begs the question "Why are you asking here, then?". It's not a good way to ask for help.

Even under the new limited quota regime of FCM, it allows each project to send 600K messages per minute. For more on this, see the documentation on sending messages at scale.
So if you reach a peak throughput below that, it is not FCM that is limiting, but your own infrastructure that calls FCM. Consider making multiple parallel calls to the FCM backend to improve throughput, and to use HTTP2 multiplexing to amortize the connection overhead per call.

I have checked scale document. but I didn't catch up on what exactly I needed to do. Is there any change on the FCM setting or if possible can you please provide an example?

The unofficial Firebase Admin SDK for PHP (Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer) enables you to send FCM messages with a throughput of ~500 messages per second (this benchmark was done on a local computer with mediocre internet connection) by calling the FCM API Endpoint with HTTP/2 asynchronously.
You could chunk the messages and push commands to an, again asynchronous, queue with multiple consumers to handle a large set of messages in a shorter amount of time.
This assumes that you currently do send one message at a time to individual users. Unless each message is different/personalized (which I doubt), this is highly inefficient, though.
The far better solution would be to subscribe the target devices to an FCM topic (e.g. retroactively with an Admin SDK, or from each device (iOS, Android, Web), send a single message to the topic and let Firebase handle an efficient delivery.
