# FCM subscribe topics to multiple senders

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know its possible to get the fcm token from multiple senders.I want to subscribe **topic** to multiple senders, not token. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't subscribe a *topic* to a *Sender*.

With that said, I think you're confusing topics as something that is similar to a registration token. It is different.

Each Sender may have their own topics that a token could subscribe to. With that, each Sender (say we have Sender1 and Sender2), may have a topic that is named `news`. Their corresponding tokens (see about enabling Multiple Senders [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981412/4625829)) must then be subscribed to both.

Comment: Your link just for 'token' but I want to using 'topic'. So is impossible to subscribe topic to multiple senders?

Comment: Each multiple senders has thier unique topic but I don't know how to subscribe. When I subscribe topic, then just 1 sender (configurated in google-services.json) got topic. How can I subscribe topic to multiple senders?

Comment: Just as what I mentioned at the start, you can't subscribe a topic to a Sender. You're going to have to create the topic for each sender and subscribe the token for each.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I wonder how can I do like 'Have to create the topic for each sender' as you said.

Comment: You could do it from the Server. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42712028/4625829)