# Firebase / FCM notifications / TOPICS : How to copy all users on a certain TOPIC directly on FCM DB?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We published an android app with firebase FCM notifications and we had 100k+ registrations on FCM database.
When we tested the notification on the users it takes hours to process and sometimes it's hanging for a while (due to 1000 limitations)

We noticed the TOPICS features on FCM that is more appropriate for broadcasting notifications.

Question : Is there a way to copy all the users to the newly created/implemented topic directly on FCM DB without updating and waiting that all the users download the new app ?

Thanks
Willy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't copy the tokens to a topic, you just subscribe them to it (I'm assuming that the wording is just wrong, but I figure it might confuse others).

With that said, you could use the [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances). You could subscribe a token one by one or by using `batchAdd` (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42712028/4625829)).